# What is a proper way to initialize Akka EventStream listeners in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have an internal audit log, that I send to EventStream in default AkkaSystem. There was no problem with sending events, I just inserted an EventSteam, and published my events there.

The problem was to start EventStream listener when Play application starts. I tried going with simple guice configuration, this did not work, as I expected because Guice creates this bean lazily

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("auditEventListener")
def auditEventListener(actorSystem: ActorSystem, auditEventCollection: AuditEventCollection): ActorRef = {
    val listenerRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new AuditEventListener(auditEventCollection)))
    val subscribed = actorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(listenerRef, classOf[AuditEvent])
    if (!subscribed)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to subscribe to events")
    listenerRef
}
```

So I decided to go with Global object, and moved initialization there:

```
  override def onStart(app: Application) = {
     val listenerRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new AuditEventListener(auditEventCollection)))
     actorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(listenerRef, classOf[AuditEvent])
  }
```

In this case - onStart is called twice in tests, and the same event published twice in AuditLog, also this is not recommended anymore by Play.

So. I choose a middle ground

```
   override def onStart(app: Application) = {
     app.injector.instanceOf(BindingKey(classOf[ActorRef]).qualifiedWith("auditEventListener"))
   }
```

This works - listener receives events and initialized only once.

Since I don't like inventing wheels, I wonder.
How should I do it "Scala/Playframework" way?